# Camel case converter in an excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to convert a field in an excel sheet (e.g. REC_LEN) to camel case. I am using this formula to do that

```
=LEFT(A1) & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_",""), LEN( SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))-1)
```

This is giving me results like RecLen. I want to convert my first letter to lowercase too (The expected output is recLen). Can somebody help me out with this? I am not too familiar with excel formulae. Not sure if this has been already asked before but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1)) & MID(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_",""),2,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

With Office 365 we can use:

```
=LET(
    rr,A1,
    x,TEXTSPLIT(rr,"_"),
    CONCAT(LOWER(TAKE(x,,1)),PROPER(DROP(x,,1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but this does not work for fields with multiple underscores. Like LAST_UPDT_DT.

Answer (score 6):

Just use =PROPER(A1) on the another cell and you have it done.

Comment: The OP intended to lower case the first letter and remove underscores, which using Proper alone does not do.

Answer (score 3):

You were so close! Just wrap your *left* expression in a `LOWER`:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1)) & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_",""), LEN( SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   =LOWER(LEFT(A1)) & MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))
```

This works perfectly for creating camel case when there is no space or underscore between words.

So HelloWorld will become helloWorld.

Answer (score 0):

This converts to camel case:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(LEFT(A5)) & MID(A5,2,LEN(A5)),"_","")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

using replace,

`=LOWER(LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1))&PROPER(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("_",A1),""))`